# appengine console for in-development application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a possibility of having a remote_api_shell.py like feature for the application under development. The remote_api_shell.py asks us to point to deployed application and gives the repl console. I found a following limitation while using remote_api_shell, if I os.chdir to my development directory, I was not able to use the modules which I am writing using google apis.

I felt the need for local console as I was trying to data-model an app under development and I had to constantly try/change my models, without going through the request handling layer or uploading the application. This may be good to try out various features of Model in the interactive session. con.appspot.com provides console in the browser and I feel not suitable to writing classes or importing small test modules.

Something like this does not work as it requires an _app to hold on.

```
 import setapipaths # Sets the paths to google appengine apis
 import sys

 from google.appengine.ext import db

 class TodoList(db.Model):
     name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

 class TodoItem(db.Model):
     user = db.UserProperty(required=True)
     date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
     belongs_to = db.Reference(TodoList)
     description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
     rating = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
     score = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)

 todolist = TodoList()
 todolist.name = "firstline"
 todolist.put()

 obj1 = TodoItem(user='senthil',belongs_to=todolist.key(),description="something",rating=10,score=5)
 obj1.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

Doh! I found the answer as soon I as posted this question.

Step 1: Run your app under-development in one shell session

```
python dev_appserver.py app
```

the application by default runs under port 8080

Step 2: Open another shell session and use the remote_api_shell.py to connect to the running instance.

```
PYTHONPATH=. remote_api_shell.py -s localhost:8080 app
```

There you will get the app console for experimenting.

Previously I was trying to use the `remote_api_shell.py` on the local application, without running it.

**Update**: In addition, I found that http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive console provides the ability to write full snippet.